# Missing character: There is no . (U+002E) in font nullfont! when using samples option in \addplot3

Tags: pgfplots, luatex

Can someone tell my, why using the option `samples=10` in `\addplot3` gives several `Missing character: There is no ... in font nullfont!` warnings?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}
            \addplot3[samples=10] {sin(x)};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Edit (daleif) the full error is

```
Missing character: There is no . in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no 0 in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no 1 in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no p in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no t in font nullfont!
```

Comment: As Ulrike mentions in her answer it is a bug. The full error in an indicator as this is clearly someone trying to typeset `.01pt` in `nullfont` (tikz tends to use `nullfont` whenever it does not expect output.

Comment: tikz unfortunately always relied on nullfont to ignore spurious characters in paths, prevously just went to the log but on recent latex releases missing character messages go to the terminal as well. the example is generating `.01pt` as unexpected characters in some tikz path

Comment: It is unfortunate since this causes `latexmk` to fail when used with `-Werror`.

Comment: @ManuelSchmidt these warnings can be harmless, but from the ones I investigated the majority came (like this one) from a real bug that could affect the output. So be grateful that the warning is now less hidden.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Yes, I do not worry about this warning. My problem is, that I cannot catch real errors (e.g. missing refs/labels) anymore with `-Werror` until this gets fixed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it is a bug. pgfplots use `\ifnum` instead of `\ifdim`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\makeatletter
\def\pgfplotsforeachtodomain@@.#1\relax{%
    \pgf@xa=0.#1pt %   
    \ifdim\pgf@xa>0.01pt  % % <----corrected \ifdim instead of ifnum
        \def\pgfplotsretval{}%
        \def\pgfplotsretvalb{}%
    \else
        \edef\pgfplotsretvalb{\the\c@pgf@counta}%
    \fi
}%
\makeatletter
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}
            \addplot3[samples=10] {sin(x)};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Caveat: I'm not completly sure what pgfplots is testing here, and if using `\ifdim` gives the expected result. The `\ifnum` converted the length into a number by using the `sp` unit, and so the test was always true unless `#1` is very small and this looks rather senseless.

Comment: Got it today... ¿has been reported to `pgfplots` github? Should I do it?